# How to set top-center position for pnotify

Tags: position, pnotify

How to set non pixels position?
I try this

```
var stack = { "dir1": "down", "dir2": "right", "firstpos1": 50, "firstpos2": 50 };
```

But I this it is bad because of different screen resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a similar question with an answer [here](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/issues/46). As per the first example in the [stacks documentation](http://sciactive.com/pnotify/#stacks), you can center the initial position of the notification by setting the top/left css propreties in before_open. You also need to reposition the notification everytime the window is resized.

```js
function get_center_pos(width, top) {
  // top is empty when creating a new notification and is set when recentering
  if (!top) {
    top = 30;
    // this part is needed to avoid notification stacking on top of each other
    $('.ui-pnotify').each(function() {
      top += $(this).outerHeight() + 20;
    });
  }

  return {
    "top": top,
    "left": ($(window).width() / 2) - (width / 2)
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  new PNotify({
    title: "this is center",
    text: "blablabla",
    opacity: 0.90,
    type: "info",
    width: "390px",
    before_open: function(PNotify) {
      PNotify.get().css(get_center_pos(PNotify.get().width()));
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".ui-pnotify").each(function() {
      $(this).css(get_center_pos($(this).width(), $(this).position().top))
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Necroposting, but may help to other searchers. My solution without js recalculations:

**js:**

```
new PNotify({
    ...
    addclass: 'pnotify-center'
});
```

**css:**

```
.pnotify-center {
   right: calc(50% - 150px) !important;
}
```